# How to run multiple sql commands with SQLQuery object in java

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, hibernate, postgresql

I'm trying to use SQLQuery object with multiple sql commands. I need to split the query in order to get better performance.

```
CREATE TABLE x (
    id integer,
    key integer)

select * 
from x, users,.......
where .......

DROP TABLE x
```

Comment: It is extremely unclear what you are asking and what you have attempted to do.

Comment: You can execute only one query at a time.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis why??, i'm asking how to send 3 sql commands in one batch and not 3.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza are you sure?

Comment: Yes, pretty sure. If you don't believe it, try to append multiple SQL queries and send them to execute. If you had done this from the beginning, this question would have never arised.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza did it, this is why i'm asking, i know that you can do it when you are using JDBC with prepared statement

Comment: Not even with `PreparedStatement`s. What you can do is append them to batch and do a batch insert/update/delete. Still, that it's not the same as executing multiple sql queries at a single time. In your case, it would be better to execute the three (or more) statements in a single connection.

Comment: Are you really using Hibernate with PostGreSQL and SQL Server all together?

Comment: @Joe that's not a problem

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Thanks, can you write it as an answer and i will approve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your issue is creating and dropping tables, create a `TEMPORARY` table with drop on commit.  Then when you commit your db transaction the table will be gone.

The issue is that usually you only get the last statement's results returned.  If you need something else, look at wrapping with a user defined function and presenting a single tabular result set back.